# How to Properly Add Double Quotes to a Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a textarea to include a set of double quotes at the start and end of the textarea value. The below code works in that double quotes are added to the start and end of the field, but if the user enters text and then goes back to the field, multiple double quote sets can be added. How can I prevent this? A jQuery solution is also acceptable.

```
<textarea name="quoteName" id="quoteName" style="width:100%" rows="4" onChange="quotes();" autofocus></textarea>

function quotes(){
  var quoteValueBefore = document.getElementById("quoteName").value;
  var ensureQuotes = "\"" + quoteValueBefore + "\"";
  document.getElementById("quoteName").value = ensureQuotes;
}
```

Comment: Why are you wanting the quotes? I personally think it would be easier to apply this on the server side.  Either way you can check the first char and last char of the quoteName, if it is equal to a quote you don't pre/append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the text already begins with a quote, and if it already ends with one. If either is missing, add it.

Also check that the length >= 2, otherwise `"` would pass the test (ends with a quote? check. begins with a quote? check.)

```js
function quotes() {
  var quoteValue = document.getElementById("quoteName").value;

  if (!quoteValue.match(/^"/))
    quoteValue = '"' + quoteValue;

  if (!quoteValue.match(/"$/))
    quoteValue += '"';

  if (quoteValue.length < 2)
    quoteValue += '"';

  document.getElementById("quoteName").value = quoteValue;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="quoteName" id="quoteName" style="width:100%" rows="4" onChange="quotes();" autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul! If I click into the textbox and type test it successfully adds the double quotes upon leaving the field, if I go back to the field and type test after the second test, it doesn't remove the middle set of double quotes. How can I prevent that? Thanks again.  

Example: "test"test"

Comment: You can always do a `quoteValue.replace(/"/g, "");` before anything else, but then what if someone *wants* quotes in their value? If you need the quotes on the server side, or somewhere else, why not just add them there?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkQuotes(id) {
  str = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (str[0] != '"') {
    str = '"'.concat(str);
  }
  if (str[str.length - 1] != '"') {
    str = str.concat('"')
  }
  return str
}

function quotes() {
  withQuotes = checkQuotes("quoteName");
  document.getElementById("quoteName").value = withQuotes
}
```

```html
<textarea name="quoteName" id="quoteName" style="width:100%" rows="4" onchange="quotes()">testing the quotes feature</textarea>
```

This snippet will check if the first character is a quote, if it isn't it will prepend it.  It also checks if the last character is a quote, if it isn't it will append it.  This probably isn't the most friendly UI solution, and I recommend either adding this through CSS if you're using it for display purposes, or using PHP or whatever you're doing for the backend form submission.